# How to launch an app using NSURL and -openURL:?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

There are a few apps which I find very helpful and want to recommend to my users inside my app. If one such app is installed, and the user taps the button, I want to launch that app. Otherwise open the app page in the App Store app.

UIApplication provides a -canOpenURL: method which I think can be used to check if an app exists on the device. With -openURL: an app can be launched. But how do I construct an NSURL to launch an app?

The apps I want to refer to don't have any special registered URL scheme, at least not that I know of. All I know is their name and app ID.

Is that possible or must the developers of these apps update their apps to support custom URL opening schemes?

Answer (score 1):

It is only possible to open the app by url in case it has known registered URL scheme (it may me your application or one of the existing iOS schemes)

Comment: So if I don't know the URL scheme of these apps from the developers there is no chance to launch it?

Comment: Absolutely right. Also, only a few of the apps have URL schemes.

Comment: You may want to contact the developer of the apps you like, and either they could provide the scheme for the app, or they could incorporate that in the next version of their app.  Frankly, I can see both sides of it: on one side, it is locked down and we can't do the cool stuff we want to.  On the other side, Apple wants to isolate and maintain security such that apps can't trample each other.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [list of public URL schemes](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes). This however is just a fraction of what is out there in the market. It may however be helpful for you.